# How to Let Python Connect to a SQL Server Database

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, odbc

hello I am trying to connect python to sql server , but only connect on system database like master dtabase , i dont can connect to my databases , someone knows how i can configure my database to connect in python?

```
import pyodbc as odbc
DRIVER_NAME ='SQL SERVER'
SERVER_NAME='BOOK-FFARDRU9TD'
DATABASE_NAME='Teste' #dosent work with my datavbases
NAME='pierre'
PASS='987652'
connection_string=f"""
    DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};
    SERVER={SERVER_NAME};
    DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};
    Trusted_Connection= yes;
    UID={NAME};
    PWD={PASS};
    """
conn=odbc.connect(connection_string)
print("aaaaaaaaaaa")
```

and the error is :

```
pyodbc. ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Unable to open the "Teste" database requested by logon. Logon failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Unable to open the "Teste" database prompted by logon. Logon failed. (4060)')
```

I need help to solve this problem , I think the user that I am trying to use to acess the DB dont have permission , but I dont know how do that.

Comment: `Teste != Test` so your error doesn't match

Comment: May I suggest you edit the question to hide your user, pass and server name. Just on the off chance someone decided to cause mischief. Use something like `myname`, `mypass`, `myserver`. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, but the information in the code is already changed, I put it just to fill in illustrative

Comment: @NebularNerd As the error is a login error I don't think that would be an issue :)

Comment: That's an SQL Server issue, not Python. You need to research SQL Server's auth the permissions system

Answer (score 1):

The error message mentions a database named 'Test', but in the code it is written as 'Teste'.

In a SQL query, you can grant permissions to a database to a specified user with this line:

```
USE ML_Samples //Database name
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'MySQLLogin' //User name
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/security/user-permission?view=sql-server-ver16